# while running fill sinks in QGIS 2.14.6 i am getting this error..what is the reason?

Tags: qgis

Algorithm Fill sinks starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\c8603b46118c467c8c9d349dd289bde8\dem11.sgrd" -FILES "F:\my projct\dem11.tif"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)" -DEM "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\c8603b46118c467c8c9d349dd289bde8\dem11.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 1 -RESULT "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\0142c11dfb5940c2b88c132dfe44efdd\RESULT.sdat"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>PATH=c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.14\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\c8603b46118c467c8c9d349dd289bde8\dem11.sgrd" -FILES "F:\my projct\dem11.tif"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

---

## #####

#### ### ##

#### # ## ## #### #

#### ##### ## #

# ## ##### #

---

---

library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\modules\io_gdal.dll
library name: Import/Export - GDAL/OGR
tool name : GDAL: Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)

---

Parameters

Grids: No objects
Files: "F:\my projct\dem11.tif"
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor

loading: F:\my projct\dem11.tif

Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 4789

Columns: 4196

Transformation:

x' = 393016.204524 + x * 30.555556 + y * 0.000000

y' = 2596593.474508 + x * 0.000000 + y * -30.555556

warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
using cellsize: 30.555556

loading band [1/1]

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>saga_cmd ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)" -DEM "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\c8603b46118c467c8c9d349dd289bde8\dem11.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 1 -RESULT "C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\0142c11dfb5940c2b88c132dfe44efdd\RESULT.sdat"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

---

## #####

#### ### ##

#### # ## ## #### #

#### ##### ## #

# ## ##### #

---

---

library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\modules\ta_preprocessor.dll
library name: Terrain Analysis - Preprocessing
tool name : Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)
author : Copyrights (c) 2003 by Volker Wichmann

---

Load grid: C:\Users\WATERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing1d1d4cddaf354226b0924459ec8556cf\c8603b46118c467c8c9d349dd289bde8\dem11.sgrd...

Parameters

Grid system: 30.555556; 4790x 4197y; 393031.482302x 2468367.085619y
DEM: dem11
Filled DEM: Filled DEM
Minimum Slope [Degree]: 1.000000

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Filled DEM
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AbhishekMohite! Try moving your .tif file from your `F:` drive to your `C:` drive.

Comment: gdal_MrSID dll is missing. MrSID driver/API is not free/open source :(

Comment: I have similar problem. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?